# Undefined Argument when using Callback function for express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, routes

Currently, I am using many routes in Express. Some of the routes can be quite lengthy. A common route look like the following:

```
router.get('/api/comments', function(req, res, next){
  Comment.find({"user": req.payload._id}).exec(function(err,comments){
    if(err){return next(err); }
    res.json(comments);
  })
}
```

This works fine. But I am calling routes multiple times and it can be quite lengthy. So I am trying to create a callback function which can be invoked by the various routes. E.g.

```
var testFunction = function(req, res, next){
  Comment.find({"user": req.payload._id}).exec(function(err,comments){
    if(err){return next(err); }
    res.json(comments);
  })
}

router.get('/api/comments', testFunction(req,res,next));
```

However, I will always get a "req is not defined" error on the last line. Just wondering what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router` takes a function as argument not the result of executing that function.

`router.get('/api/comments', testFunction);` will work.

Comment: It does work. But then if I need to pass some arguments to the function, how do I do it?

Comment: @Sydney - Either use `.bind()` to bind the arguments or use an anonymous function that does nothing by call your function with the desired arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `router.get('/api/comments', testFunction);` instead of `router.get('/api/comments', function(req, res, next)`